# getting a 3 router setup to work properly

Tags: router

I have 3 routers hooked up in the following way.  The main router is connected to WAN on each of the other 2 routers. However only one of the routers connected to the main router is connecting to the internet, but not the other.  Is there any specific ip configuration or other configurations that need to be changed to allow them to work?

How specifically do they need to be configured? What should I look for??

Comment: Each of the routers need to be on a separate subnet all the way to the internet.  Make sure DHCP is enabled on the routers.

Comment: what exactlly will you achive? maybe uing the main router and to switches will do it also?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want this setup to expand your wireless network using wired access points.
To do this;

1. Connect the main router to the internet modem on the WAN port.
   Enable DHCP on this one.
2. Configure the "slave" routers;

   - DISABLE DHCP
   - Connect to the main router LAN port from the slave routers LAN port (right - do not use the WAN ports)
   - Use the same SSID and password on all routers, but I would recommend to use different bands (1-11) on each of the three routers

More info:
http://www.tested.com/tech/298-how-to-use-an-old-router-to-expand-your-wi-fi-network/

Comment: would this work for different network ssids as well?